# Best practice to switch on 4 power supplies from one single source

Tags: power-supply, power, rgb, led-matrix

First of all, I am a self taught maker with a passion for LED lights. So far I have built a few display signs for indoor applications, where one microcontroller is connected to a number of RGB Led Matrices (not more than 10) and these are then connected to a few power supplies. In each of those displays, I ended up having to connect each power supply to mains. So far this has worked out pretty well. However all power supplies individually provided 5v and not more than 10A, for a total of 20A, depending on the number of Led panels. Something I was able to handle easily indoors.

This time, I need to build a much bigger display for outdoors, made out of 32 [LED RGB panels like these ones](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32848483770.html). They will be divided in 4 groups, each with 8 RGB panels, each powered by an individual power supply (5v/60A each), [like these ones](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32816968186.html). I have been guaranteed that each power supply is enough to power 8 panels.

When the project will be finished, I will have 4 independent power supplies, each connected to 8 panels; in theory I will have to connect each one of them to a power source, located near the install. Is there a way to power all supplies at once from one single source? Should I connect them in series and then connect the first one to mains? Also, as each power supply will provide up to 60A, are they safe to be connected to a socket, the type of which one can find in a UK household or office space?

I am still developing the design, I am planning to position the 4 power supplies on the back of the display. Cables connecting each power supply to the LED matrices will be 40-50cm long. I would like the display to be movable, and it will never be positioned more than 5 meters away from a power source.

Datasheet for the above mentioned power supplies are:

- Output power: 300W Max
- Leakage current: <1mA (Vin: 230)
- Working temperature: -30 ° C ~ 50 ° C
- Cooling method: air cooling
- Storage temperature: -40~80°C
- Input voltage: 110/220Vac (manual dialing), 47-63Hz
- Insulation voltage: I/P-O/P: 3.0KVac; I/P-FG: 1.5KVac; O/P-FG: 0.5KVac
- Safety standards: GB4943, EN60950
- Protection function: input undervoltage, overload protection, short circuit protection
- Power factor: 0.50@230Vac
- Size: length × width × height = 217mm × 117mm × 30mm

Comment: I have serious doubts that a 15€ power supply can reliably deliver 60A. Generally, it's very desirable to have your low-voltage power source very close to the consumer – Ohm's laws are not nice to you if you try to transport 60A over 2m of wiring, unless that wiring has a very thick diameter.

Comment: Thank you, I should indeed look into other brands as well! So far I only used MeanWell power supplies, they retail for $30 from the US (probably 46$ = 36€) after taxes and delivery. These ones are sold by the same supplier that sells the RGB panels

Comment: the cheapest Meanwell supply would be in the > $50 range, [says digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mean-well-usa-inc/NEL-400-5/1866-3529-ND/7705247) ([list](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-external-internal-off-board/ac-dc-converters/133)). I habitually don't trust any aliexpress sellers; that seems to be a good idea.

Comment: good point! thanks for the links. I was looking exactly at the same ones on sale on amazon.co.uk as per your link. £29.99, each, could definitively use those, only need to know if it makes sense to connect them in series as per my original post

Comment: if things that cost $50 from the large suppliers are on amazon for GBP 29.99 (ca $40), then those are very likely counterfeits and should not be expected to operate properly within the same bounds as the genuine parts. A cheaper, but reliable source than digikey would be [arrow](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/nel-400-5/mean-well-enterprises?utm_campaign=octopart_2018&utm_currency=GBP&utm_keyword=NEL-400-5&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_content=inv_listing&utm_source=octopart) for this.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have thought that they could be counterfeits... and don't mind spending some more and be safe. Great link btw, I didn't know Arrow.

Comment: Make sure you get appropriately sized cables to connect your displays, and you know your LED panels' minimum supply voltage! For example, 60 A through a solid copper wire of 3mm diameter drop ca 0.15 V per meter of wiring, and you need to account for "both directions" (VCC and Ground) of your 50cm.

Comment: Uh, a power factor of 0.5 isn't a good idea in a high-powered supply, to be honest. That's like the worst possible PF you'd get. These wouldn't be legal to sell in Europe.